# Modify print job with one liner - missing output command

Tags: perl, printing, command-line-interface

I am using Perl with our printing output system. Usually we call perl scripts, but I am just replacing a keyword with another word. In a console and a test file this worked with this one liner:

`perl -pi -e "s/KEYWORD1/KEYWORD2"`

Now I wanted to use it with our system and it gives me the error that there is no output file created. As I am fairly new to the field of Perl and want to have it used within a one liner, how can i do this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Kind regards

Comment: You're missing a `/`, and possibly a filename.

Answer (score 1):

As *Shawn* mentioned in the comment, you are missing `/` in the substitution command `s///`. You are also missing a filename, which is needed for the `-i` option.

Both of these fail and print a warning and an error:

```
perl -pi -e "s/KEYWORD1/KEYWORD2" < foo

# or:
cat foo | perl -pi -e "s/KEYWORD1/KEYWORD2"
```

They print messages:

```
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.
```

Correct usage:

```
perl -pi -e 's/KEYWORD1/KEYWORD2/' foo

# or:
perl -pe 's/KEYWORD1/KEYWORD2/' < foo

# or:
another_command | perl -pe 's/KEYWORD1/KEYWORD2/'
```